# Microcontroller specific codes in OS (Contiki)

Tags: operating-system, contiki

I am working on creating a port for LPC1347 to contiki-os. I have 2 questions:

1: What i do not understand is how would the os know what architecture the hardware follows ie, whether is Harvard architecture or Neumann architecture. The microcontroller has 2 srams, so does the compiler or linker provide the libraries(addresses of memories) for the OS? Also, how does the OS know the address of RAM, is it provided by linker?

2: Contiki does not have device/peripheral driver API so how do i work about 
adding peripherals? I see there are functions like leds_toggle in apps/shell/shell-blink.c . My question is how can i know what libraries are/would be required to run a basic LED program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Makefiles select the compiler and pass the appropriate parameters. Have a look at the Makefiles in platform and cpu. They set the compiler (`CC`) and lots of flags for the compiler (`CFLAGS`) and linker (`LDFLAGS`).
The platform is selected by setting the `TARGET`-make-parameter and the platform selects the CPU.

As for the additional question: The make-files also select the files to use for compilation.

Also try running make with `V=1`, then the calls to the compiler will be printed to th output.

Comment: There is no gcc compiler for lpc1347, what can i do about it? RTX RTOS was ported to lpc via lpcxpresso IDE, so, what are my options?

Comment: There is no gcc code generator for ARM Cortex-M3?  What about this; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ARM_Cortex-M_development_tools

Comment: I am sorry, i am new to this and i am trying to figure out where what fits in, yes i have installed gcc arm compiler, Thanks.

Comment: @morty , i have made a few changes in the question, it would be great of you could help me. Thanks.